# Links e Scripts não encontrados com CI-3

Tags: css, html5, codeigniter

Coloquei meu `header` e `footer` dentro de uma pasta `templates` que fica dentro d pasta `views`, quando tento carregar o CSS o navegador retorna o `erro 404 - not found`, mas eu estou seguindo de acordo com o que a IDE mostra para não ter erro.

Abaixo a estrutura de pastas.

```
Views
assets
   css
   js
   image
   font
   font_awesome
errors
template
   header
   footer
painel_view.php (pagina index)
```

Como estrou dentro de `template` eu preciso subir uma pasta `../` e depois entrar em assets certo?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

O arquivo de `css` esta dentro da pasta normalmente.

Comment: Colocando com [base_url](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url) vc consegue acessar corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre trabalho com a `base_url()`, pode conferir a [documentação no link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=base_url#base_url)

Ou seja, defino lá no config.php a url principal do meu projeto, e a cada vez que vou carregar um arquivo, chamo primeiro a base_url e depois o resto do caminho do arquivo. Lembrando que deverá configurar o helper `url` lá no `autoload.php` também.

Outro ponto é manter teus arquivos de assets na pasta específica para eles.
Dentro da pasta view, serão somente os arquivos de `front end`, assim como na models somente as `classes` e na pasta Controllers, somente os arquivos com `regras de negócio`.
Eu prefiro usar os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
Raiz do Projeto: (www.site.com.br)
    assets
       css
       js
       imagens
    application
       (todos os diretórios do framework)
```

No teu caso, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Seguindo a lógica que lá no arquivo config.php está

```
config['base_url'] = 'http://www.site.com.br';
```

Quando for renderizado no navegador, ficará assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.site.com.br/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```